# Time delay in butter filtered trace, why and how to remove it?

Tags: python, filtering

I'm filtering a time trace in python using `butter` from `scipy.signal`. I use here a low-pass (on a noisy 100 Hz sinus sampled at 10000 points/sec, for example), but the following is true for any filter (low, high, band).

The filtered trace has always a delay with respect to the original (see figure). This delay depends on the parameters of the filter (frequencies, order).

Do you have a (simple) explanation why this delay is there? And is it possible to programmatically eliminate it? The goal would be to have the filtered trace laying right on top of the raw trace. If I chop off the first N points of the filtered trace, it could be ok, but how much is N as a function of the filter parameters?

[image: low pass filtering a noisy sinus at 100Hz]

The code I used is based on [this](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/ButterworthBandpass):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='lowpass', analog=False)
    return b, a

def lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5, plots=True):
    ''' fs : sampling freq. (pts/s) '''
    cutoff = float(cutoff)
    fs = float(fs)
    t = np.arange(0, len(data)/fs, 1/fs)
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    if plots:
        plot_filter(a,b,fs,y,t,data, cutoff)
    return y

def plot_filter(a,b,fs,y,t,data, f1=0, f2=0):
    ''' a,b from filterfs = sampling freq.
        f1 = cutoff, f2 = 0 (butter_lowpass)
        f1 = lowcut, f2 = highcut (butter_bandpass)
    '''
    w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=8000)
    plt.figure(555)
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.semilogx(0.5*fs*w/np.pi, np.abs(h), 'b')
    if f1:
        plt.plot(f1, 0.5*np.sqrt(2), 'ko')
        plt.axvline(f1, color='k')
    if f2:
        plt.plot(f2, 0.5*np.sqrt(2), 'ko')
        plt.axvline(f2, color='k')
    plt.xlim(0, 0.5*fs)
    plt.title("Filter Frequency Response")
    plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.grid()
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(t, data, 'b-', label='data')
    plt.plot(t, y, 'g-', linewidth=2, label='filtered')
    plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
```

where the signal and the filters are

```
ra = .1*randn(10000) + np.sin(2*np.pi*100*arange(10000)/10000.)
lowpass_filter(ra, 200.,  10000., order=4)
```

Comment: This is a well known phenomenon with butterworth filtering, so you may want to search on _butterworth filter time delay_ for some hints on why this happens a and how to cancel or adjust for it. I may post an answer later if I'm not beaten to it.

Comment: @MikeSatteson This isn't exactly restricted to Butterworth filters... In fact, there are very few filters of any sort, digital or analog, that do not introduce some delay. Granted, some have shorter delays than others, but the fact is that if you are going to compute an output based on more than one input sample, there will by definition be a delay introduced...

Comment: @twalberg agreed and an important point.  I added butterworth, because that seemed to be the filter being applied in this case, perhaps I should have made a more general statement.  Thanks for your expansion of this discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want is the phase response Bode plot for your system.  You can obtain this using [scipy.signal.bode](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bode.html) on your system, that is:

```
from scipy.signal import bode
w, mag, phase = bode((b, a))
```

Where `b` and `a` are your filter coefficients.  Confusingly, `w` is in rad/s and `phase` is in degrees.  `phase` is the shift that you are seeing.  To get the time shift divide by the frequency (degrees per second). You'll probably want to pass your own `w` to bode to get the frequency range that you want.

For a tutorial see for example [Signals and Systems](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Signals_and_Systems).

Comment: @MikeSatterson : phase is an array. Can I get the delay as a single number out of `phase`? I'd like to plot the signal with something like `plot(time_array, signal_array)` and the filtered with `plot(time_array+delay, signal_array_filtered)`. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: @fpdx if you take a look at [scipy.signal.bode](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bode.html), you'll see that it is quite flexible.  You should be able to pass it an "array" of one point, the frequency you're interested in and get the results for that frequency.

Answer (score 3):

This question ended long back - but I saw a solution to this in an answer to another similar question:

[Butterworth-filter x-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098384/butterworth-filter-x-shift)

Use the filtfilt function instead of the lfilter function. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html

In the `lowpass_filter` function change the below line:

```
y = lfilter(b, a, data)
```

to:

```
y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
```