# Butterworth-filter x-shift

Tags: python, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

I have a signal and want to bandpass-filter it:

```
def butter_bandpass_prep(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    """Butterworth bandpass auxilliary function."""
    nyq = 0.5 * fs # Minimal frequency (nyquist criterion)
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass(src, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    """Butterworth bandpass filter."""
    b, a = butter_bandpass_prep(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    dst = lfilter(b, a, src)
    return dst
```

However, my signal does not start at zero which seems to cause problems as the filtered signal is shifted in x-direction. How can I compensate for this?[image: blue: signal, red: filtered]
Or maybe the butterworth filter is not the filter of choice?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filtfilt`, which will filter the signal twice, once forwards and once backwards. This will eliminate all phase shifts, but double the stopband attenuation:

```
dst = filtfilt(b, a, src)
```

Comment: Awesome! That was what I needed!
However, I don't really understand why there is a shift. Do you have a link which (at least basically) explains what happens there?